# Multiple Quick Access Entries for Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

I've been running the Windows 10 betas since January and have since a few months back had an extra Desktop icon in the Quick Access section of my Explorer windows. I always assumed it was some weird bug so haven't bothered fixing it until now.

[image: Quick Access Toolbar]

Clicking on the icon doesn't do anything, i.e. I'm not being transferred to the Desktop folder. Right clicking and getting the Properties of the object seems to indicate that the object is not pointing anywhere at all. Unpinning the item doesn't do anything either.

[image: Properties window]

Does anyone have a clue on how to unpin/remove this object?

(p.s. sorry for the swedish screenshots)

Comment: Wow that's weird. The properties are completely empty, no name or nothing? Perhaps there is a registry key for it.

Comment: Is there no "remove" option offered when you right-click it?

Comment: @TECHIE07 There is an unpin option but clicking it doesn't yield any result.